# FormSubmit.co reCAPTCHA

Tags: html, recaptcha

I'm using FormSubmit.co on my contact page, so that users can send emails to me from that page.

This service (from tutorials to and the documentation) is supposed to automatically give you a reCAPTCHA. You can disable it if you want to, but it's not reccomended.

My problem is I've just gone through the really basic set up, followed the documenation, all that. But, I have no reCAPTCHA. I didn't accidentally disable it, It was never there then went away.

I am using a website builder. It's a Monstroid template, it's been cumbersome to use with some packages, maybe that's the issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

If you're form includes this input

`<input type="hidden" name="_captcha" value="false"></input>`

removing this input  could actually enable reCAPTCHA

as this  input disables reCAPTCHA

Comment: This is not correct, please do your research before answering.